# C# Comparing Textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am programming a basic game where the program gets a random word from a dictionary and displays certain letters for the player to guess.

It would look something like this : G_m_ , user enters: Game - Correct

However what is happening is that the answer is only shown to be correct if the user enters G_m_ , which is exactly the same as what is shown previously. I know this has to do with the following piece of incorrect code :

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox4.Text == textBox3.Text)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;         
            timer1.Stop();                  
            MessageBox.Show("You Guessed The Word !");
```

In textbox4 I am storing what the player has entered while in textBox3 I am storing the random, partial word from the dictionary.

```
 textBox3.Text = GetPartialWord(lines[new Random().Next(lines.Length)]);
```

Any ideas on how to compare the original word in textBox3 and not the partial word with that of textBox4 ? Keeping in mind that I still want to show the partial word in textBox3 for the user to guess?

TextBox3: G_m_

TextBox4: Game

Answer: Correct

Thanks,
R

Comment: If the first textbox' text is `G_m_`, surely somewhere in the code you have the answer to the question? You can compare with `TextBox1.Text == TextBox2.Text`.

Comment: I'm confused. There are 3 strings here...the answer, the hint, and what the user guesses, right? And why do you have the answer in a text box? Also, keep in mind you'll need to allow for capitalization and other variations in detecting the correct guess

Comment: @J.McCabe I did not yet add a hint to the game. There is just the answer and what the user guesses. Yes, regarding the capitalisation I will remove all capital letter, unless if the word is a name or anything of the sort.

Comment: But "G_m_" in textbox3 is the hint isn't it??

Comment: Well, now I see your point and correctly I was missing the third string, I was using G_m_ as the answer. I will alter the code and see how it works. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: are u using windows form? or webform?

Comment: Windows Form @Valkyriee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store full word from the dictionary (non-partial) and compare user input with full word:

```
private string word; // assign it when you get word from the dictionary

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox4.Text == word)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;         
        timer1.Stop();                  
        MessageBox.Show("You Guessed The Word !");
    }
}
```

Also make textBox3 (one with partial word) read-only or even replace it with label.

And use some meaningful names for controls. E.g.

- `textBox4` => `answerTextBox`
- `textBox3` => `hintTextBox`
- `button2` => `answerButton`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! I will alter to fit my purposes.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, sorry for any misunderstandings, and I will keep this in mind for further questions. Could you please advise on what I could improve in this question ?

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy don't you still need to allow for capitalization differences and hanging spaces, etc., rather than doing a straight '==' compare?

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy, excuse my complete lack of knowledge, but i am not able to assign `word` to the word I get from the dictionary.

`hintTextBox.Text = word[new Random().Next(word.Length)];` is how I am getting my random word from the dictionary.

Comment: @UnknownR if your dictionary has name `word` then you should use some other name for variable holding answer. Also as McCabe pointed you probably should ignore white spaces and capitalization of letters when comparing answer with word `if (String.Equals(textBox4.text.Trim(), word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))`